# Apache ANT Version issues during Netbeans Building

Tags: java, apache, netbeans, ant

I'm trying to build a java project using netbeans ide,but i keep getting

```
Please build using Ant 1.8.0 or higher
```

error,i think this is due some version difference in the netbeans IDEs,

How can i resolve this issue

Comment: can you tell us what version of ant you have? or if you have installed?

Comment: I have netbeans IDE 6.8 i downloaded the 1.8.4 version of the ANT and extracted in the ant bin folder within the netbeans folder,but the same error again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In NetBeans options, you can set Ant home. Point this to the other installation.

Mine is:
/usr/local/netbeans-7.2.1/java/ant

the default installed with netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for me...
I got ant version 1.9.10 and java openjdk 11.0.6 (on linux LEAP 15.1)

I want to build without launching Netbeans 10 in order to automate the copy/build process of my application stored on a distant server (lock down style ^^).

each time I use the command `ant -buildfile build.xml` I got this error message :{

After seeking and observing, I find out that netbeans uses its "own" ant version but either the command, outputed to Outout tab,

```
ant -f /netbeans/java/MagicArena -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
```

nore

```
/usr/local/netbeans/extide/ant/bin/ant -f /netbeans/java/MagicArena -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean
```

...are giving (BIG) satisfaction :{

I got the same message at command line:

```
/netbeans/java/MagicArena/nbproject/build-impl.xml:111: Java 9 support requires Ant 1.10.0 or higher
```

:{